# Sending data to several processes in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I want to send data to several processes. Every process does something else with that data and wait for next data. I have something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def do_work1(in_queue):
    while True:
        item = in_queue.get()
        # exit signal
        if item == None:
            return
        print "worker 1 : {}".format(item)

def do_work2(in_queue):
    while True:
        item = in_queue.get()
        # exit signal
        if item == None:
            return
        print "worker 2: {}".format(item)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_workers = 2

    manager = Manager()

    work = manager.Queue(num_workers)

    # start for workers
    pool = []
    p = Process(target=do_work1, args=(work,))
    p.start()
    pool.append(p)
    p2 = Process(target=do_work2, args=(work,))
    p2.start()
    pool.append(p2)



    work.put("1")
    work.put("2")

    for p in pool:
        p.join()
```

But after run this code I get:

```
worker 1 : 1

worker 1 : 2
```

Or:

```
worker 2 : 1

worker 1 : 2
```

I expect something like this :

```
worker 1 : 1

worker 2 : 1

worker 1 : 2

worker 2 : 2
```

What should I change if i want to obtain the result as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use multiprocessing Pipes to send the data to every process:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe

assuming the data is able to be pickled:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

You would be able to have the processes wait for the data on their end of the pipe and loop through a list of all pipes when sending out the data.

Comment: hmm, numpy.ndarray seems isn't able to be pickled

Comment: It may not be listed in the documentation since it is not a default library in Python. It is able to be pickled though.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate manual queue handling by using multiprocessing.Pool

```
import multiprocessing


def do_work1(item):
    print "worker 1: {}".format(item)


def do_work2(item):
    print "worker 2: {}".format(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)

    pool.apply_async(do_work1, (1,))
    pool.apply_async(do_work2, (1,))
    pool.apply_async(do_work1, (2,))
    pool.apply_async(do_work2, (2,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```